# Execute Applescript when application is closed

Tags: xcode, applescript

Hey Guys,
I'm a hobby iPhone Developer and I'm interested how much time I put in a certain process. I thought about using Applescript and now I'm trying to implement this.

I thought about doing it like this: Open the project using an Applescript. This script writes the current date and time to a file. And now the point. The second script should run as soon as I quit xCode. Is there a possibility to get that event? So that the second script is executed as soon as I quit Xcode? This script than should read the file with the start time and show me the time I worked on the project.

I hope you understood, what I tried to say. :-D

Sandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an idle handler to check occasionally (say every 2 sec or so) whether Xcode is still running, and continue when it no longer is. This has the advantage of working easily without any additional tools.

Another option is PFiddlesoft's [UI Actions](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uiactions/index.html), which lets you attach scripts to various events. I think it will do quits.

Comment: I justed checked UIActions out. I can't get up with it. But idle handlers sounds good. I know it's perhaps a stupid question. But what's about performance. I don't like things which are executed all few seconds. Do I have to worry about that?

Comment: No, you probably won't notice a performance issue. I have an AppleScript that runs occasionally to update some playlists in iTunes (basically a "smarter playlist" sort of thing so I don't get any repeated artists in 100 songs) and I never notice. Also, if it does become an issue, you can use the `renice` shell command to lower your script's priority so that anything else that needs running will run first.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you very much. I played a little with it but I didn't finish it yet. But I thinks that's he right aproach. :-D